# Strange spacing of dates on x-axis (D3)

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to create a simple column chart using an array of data points of the form`[datetime,value]`, for example `[1422345600000,146]`. I would like to plot these with the date on the x-axis with labeled ticks every few days. I almost managed to accomplish this, but the first couple of ticks are spaced oddly close together.

You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/9r4fqbnm/2/

I tried

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient('bottom')
    .ticks(d3.time.days,7)
    .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y"))
```

and the ticks after the first two are indeed spaced by 7 days.

I didn't find this issue online--am I missing something obvious?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is your data array. I was too lazy to dig into each value and see which one is the culprit, but basically by converting it into a human readable format and making sure the values are valid - fixes the problem:

```
  function getDate(y, m, d) {
    return new Date(y, m, d);
} 
 var data = [
[getDate(2015, 1, 27), 146], [getDate(2015, 1, 28), 132], ...,  [getDate(2015, 2, 24), 67], [getDate(2015, 2, 25), 46]
];

var startDate = data[0][0];
var endDate = data[data.length - 1][0];
```

...

http://jsfiddle.net/2L3fy90j/1/

Comment: Thanks! I had just assumed our source was valid/sorted.